# selenium web driver Unreachable browser exception with Safari on Mac

Tags: java, selenium, safari

I have written simple code to open safari web browser in eclipse with selenium web driver on  mac .also where to look for  safari exe and where to place it on mac plzz help.thanks

```
package sanityTest;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

  public class AdminLogin {
     public static void main(String[]args){
        WebDriver driver=new SafariDriver();
        //driver.close();//close the browser
    }

}
```

I am getting  this error

**strong text**Error below

Sep 24, 2016 1:22:31 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 3897
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:31 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:31 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Sep 24, 2016 1:22:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10080 ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'Vishals-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.26', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startClient(RemoteWebDriver.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.(SafariDriver.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at sanityTest.AdminLogin.main(AdminLogin.java:10)

Comment: I have latest version of both firefox  and selenium web driver on my mac and i am not sure about their compatibility..could this be a problem??

Comment: I tried with safari and fire fox both but i am getting exception here both time

Answer (score 1):

The Safari WebDriver on Mac OS currently requires that you compile, sign, and install a specific WebDriver browser extension as detailed [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver). This requires that you sign up for a free Apple developer account and get a test key to sign the extension.

Fortunately, this method of remotely automating the Safari browser is currently undergoing a transition.  With the upcoming release of Safari 10, the Webkit developers are building in native WebDriver support to the Safari browser itself.  In my opinion, the easiest way to currently automate Safari is to download the [Safari Technology Preview](https://webkit.org/downloads/) and then use the current snapshot version of Selenium to launch the WebDriver.  You can find instructions on how to use Safari's new WebDriver features [here](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/).

Comment: Thanks !! also I am facing issues with firefox and chrome driver which is something this " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /path/to/chromedriver"  I am not sure where and how to place browsers in system and set their path on this MAC system. due to whichI am unable to open any browser from eclipse web driver command.and Yes I am very new and doing it for 1st time .

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issues in initiating safari browser on mac machine, and below solution helped me. Everytime I was calling driver init, browser was getting opened but the URL was not getting hit. I am using Page object factory, with selenium , Java , maven and testng.

```
if (browserType.equals("safari")) {
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", workingDir +
            // "//driver//SafariDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver",
                    "/driver/SafariDriver.safariextz");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                    .safari();
            SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            safariOptions.getUseCleanSession();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY,
                    safariOptions);

            // deleteCookies();
            driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new SafariDriver());

            ThreadDriver.set(driver);
            // driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 850));
            getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        }
```